# Should ntpd be used on Raspbian Stretch?

Tags: debian, systemd, raspberry-pi, time, ntpd

It was installed by default on the previous distributions (jessie, wheezy, etc), but it is not so on stretch.  Before installing it, I wish to know whether there is some other preferred means to ensure time is synchronized.  I just recently discovered the timesyncd daemon, however, it does not appear to be setup.  Is timesyncd what should now be used?  If neither ntpd or timesyncd is running, how does the RPi keep time synchronized?

Comment: The [Debian Handbook](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-handbook/sect.config-misc.en.html#sect.time-synchronization) still refers to NTP.

Comment: @JeffSchaller so go with `NTP` or `timesync`?

Comment: I'm not a Debian expert, so I would go with what their handbook says. If there's discussions underway to convert from NTP to timesync, I didn't find any (that doesn't mean there isn't -- just that I didn't find it).

Comment: @JeffSchaller  My gut feel is timesync is likely preferred for a client only.

Answer (score -2):

The pi does not have a hardware clock, afaik, so `ntpd` OR `timesync` are mandatory. Given `systemd`'s track record, I would stick with `ntpd`.

Systemd track record: http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2017-15908/

You may claim, yeah, all software is vulnerable and I say fine.

However, systemd team wrote their own code instead of using road-worn glic code. Amusingly, glibc had this exact same issue some years prior ...

Why develop time-sync if you have ntpd ? I don't know of a logical explanation. I would create a systemd unit that starts ntpd to keep time and disable timesync. That is just me, I have my reasons as outlined above.

Comment: Thanks thecarpy,  As `date` displays the correct time and as you indicate there is no on-board hardware clock, something is keeping time synchronized.  But neither `ntpd` or `timesync` seem to be doing so.  Maybe I am not checking correctly. Recommendations how I should check?

Comment: Hm, on my pi, I have `time-sync.target` as output of `systemctl | grep time`, you don't ?

Comment: Ah, yes I do.  I am new to systemctl still, and was trying things like `systemctl status timesync`.

Comment: On my system (Stretch Lite), that target seems empty from `systemctl list-dependencies time-sync.target`